# Did Elrond Half-Elven have any title?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

Elrond is clearly in charge at Rivendell, and is an important and powerful person in the world at large. He is a ring-bearer, having received Vilya from his great-uncle Gil-galad. He also held a position of command in Gil-galad's army. He is of royal descent. His brother Elros Tar-Minyatur was the first king of Númenor. And yet Elrond himself seems to have no title at all.

"Half-Elven" serves more as a descriptor than a title. He is also known as the master of Imaldris, but that too seems to be a description, not a title as such. He is never, to my memory, addressed as Master.

Comment: Elves don't seem to go in for titles in lOTR. Partly, I suspect, they're burnt out on the whole thing and partly because after a few thousand years they all know who's who; all the squabbling over king-ships and hierarchy has been settled a *long* time ago. They just don't care anymore.

Comment: See my answer. He's repeatedly addressed as Master Elrond.

Comment: @TheFallen You might want to see [this interesting bug](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11015/70236).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, he was the ***Lord of Rivendell***

> The face of Elrond was ageless, neither old nor young, though in it
>   was written the memory of many things both glad and sorrowful. His
>   hair was dark as the shadows of twilight, and upon it was set a
>   circlet of silver; his eyes were grey as a clear evening, and in them
>   was a light like the light of stars. Venerable he seemed as a king
>   crowned with many winters, and yet hale as a tried warrior in the
>   fullness of his strength. **He was the Lord of Rivendell and mighty
>   among both Elves and Men.** - <sub><sup>FOTR : Chapter 1 - Many Meetings</sup></sub>

We are advised in the [Unfinished Tales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unfinished_Tales) that he was appointed as **Gil-galad's vice-regent in Eriador.**

> At this time the first Council was held, and it was there determined
>   that an Elvish stronghold in the east of Eriador should be maintained
>   at Imladris rather than in Eregion. **At that time also Gil-galad gave
>   Vilya, the Blue Ring, to Elrond, and appointed him to be his
>   vice-regent in Eriador;** but the Red Ring he kept, until he gave it to
>   Círdan when he set out from Lindon in the days of the Last Alliance.

And he also served as the **herald of Gil-galad** during the War of the Ring.

> `**I was the herald of Gil-galad** and marched with his host. I was at the Battle of Dagorlad before the Black Gate of Mordor, where we had the mastery: for the Spear of Gil-galad and the Sword of Elendil, Aiglos and Narsil, none could withstand. <sub><sup>FOTR : Chapter 2 - The Council of Elrond</sup></sub>

---

The [Silmarillion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silmarillion) has some other (informal) titles for him; "***master of Imladris***" (note the lack of capitalisation) and "***keeper of Vilya, the Ring of Air***" as well as **Master Elrond** and **Elrond Half-elven** which is, as you've noted more of a descriptor:

> Elrond Son of Eärendil and Elwing, who at the end of the First Age
>   chose to belong to the Firstborn, and remained in Middle-earth until
>   the end of the Third Age; **master of Imladris (Rivendell) and keeper of
>   Vilya, the Ring of Air,** which he had received from Gil-galad. **Called
>   Master Elrond and Elrond Half-elven**

Frodo, in Two Towers describes him as "***Elrond of Imladris***"

> My part in the Company was known to him, as to all the others. for it
>   was appointed to me by **Elrond of Imladris** himself before the whole
>   Council. On that errand I came into this country, but it is not mine
>   to reveal to any outside the Company.

---

For the record, he is repeatedly called "**Master Elrond**" by the various members of the Fellowship including Frodo, Boromir and Gandalf:

> 'And let us hope that none will ever speak it here again,' answered
>   Gandalf. '**Nonetheless I do not ask your pardon, Master Elrond**.

Comment: Of course, Tolkien doesn't use the word “Master” exactly seldom. Frodo, Gandalf, Gimli(?), Pippin and even Sam are all prefixed _Master_ at some point.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - Very true. It seems to be a general term of respect (or even mock respect). I only mentioned it because TRiG mentioned it in his question.

Comment: Wow. Language change happens much more quickly than one often imagines, in this caase during the course of my life (which I hadn't thought to be over-long yet). *Master* was, even in my youth, a sort of juvenile version of *Mister*, so its use by the ancient characters when referring to those of more limited lifespans should be read that way (and Frodo would have been *Master Frodo* in the Shire while Bilbo was still around to be called *Mister Bilbo*). When it's used "upwards", it carries a different meaning.

Comment: Also, Gil-galad, the last High King of the Noldor, appointed him as his vice-regent in the battle of the Last Alliance.

Comment: @maguirenumber6 - Cheers. Good find.

Comment: He was also "the herald of gilgalad" if that's worth adding

Comment: @DoctorTwo - Definitely worthy of mention.

Comment: "And he also served as the herald of Gil-galad during the War of the Ring."  Boy, he was a herald for a dead elf for quite a long time.  I think you wanted the The War of the Last Alliance there.